# Dynamically adding pages to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This may be a more fundamental aspect of Rails but I am very new.

I have a basic app which is sort of a basic craigslist clone.

Users - I used devise for this, users can sign up/sign in/sign out/edit their profile. 
Listings - Users can add multiple listings. Currently I have a few basic fields populating the database (title, content, phonenumber, price, location).

What I want to be able to do is the following:

I want to have a page which lists all of the ads. Currently I can do this by accessing the database and displaying all the contents. Like this:

```
<h2>LISTINGS</h2>

    <% @users.each do |u| %>
      <% u.listings.each do |i|%>
        <%=u.email %>
        <%=i.title %>
        <%=i.content %>
        <%=i.number %>
        <%=i.price %>
        <%=i.location %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

What I want to do is have this page only list the titles, each title would link to the appropriate ad. Users could then access their ad with a URL. Ideally the URL would be the title similar to what stackoverflow does "IE in the URL the title is included with "-" instead of spaces" but that is a minor concern at this point.

How is the best way to go about doing this? I may be using incorrect terminology here as I am having trouble finding information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should use as below code -

Eg :

```
<% @users.each do |u| %>
<%= link_to u.name, :controller => 'user', :action => 'show', :id  => u.id %>
<% end %>
```

I hope that you can solve your problem by using this way.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I think I would then need to add a 'show' action in the users_controller.rb ? Is that correct?